# The Math.hypo function

Tags: java, math, distance, hypotenuse

Why the math operation Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) is much faster than Math.hypo(x,y)?

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( double x=0,y=0; x<5000000; x++,y+=2 ){
            double d = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        }
        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.err.println((tb-ta));
        ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( double x=0,y=0; x<5000000; x++,y+=2 ){
            double d = Math.hypot(x,y);
        }
        tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.err.println((tb-ta));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`hypot` is usually implemented in a special way to avoid issues with overflow and underflow.  Notice that `sqrt(x*x+y*y)` returns infinity when `x` or `y` is too large and zero when both `x` and `y` are too small.

I think the usual way to get around this difficulty is by computing `z = x/y`, checking if `z*z` is in a reasonable range, and then finding `sqrt(1 + z*z) * y`.  If `z*z` is too big, you can simply return `x`, and if `z*z` is too small, you can return `y`.

Looking at the comment at the top of `__ieee754_hypot` in `eglibc-2.11.3`, I see the following chunk of a comment:

```
   So, compute sqrt(x*x+y*y) with some care as
   follows to get the error below 1 ulp:

   Assume x>y>0;
   (if possible, set rounding to round-to-nearest)
   1. if x > 2y  use
           x1*x1+(y*y+(x2*(x+x1))) for x*x+y*y
   where x1 = x with lower 32 bits cleared, x2 = x-x1; else
   2. if x <= 2y use
           t1*y1+((x-y)*(x-y)+(t1*y2+t2*y))
   where t1 = 2x with lower 32 bits cleared, t2 = 2x-t1,
   y1= y with lower 32 bits chopped, y2 = y-y1.
```

I can't see a reason for why `eglibc` does all this unless `x*x+y*y` overflows or underflows.

Comment: "Avoid overflow and underflow" That's it. Thanks tmyklebu.